# Modern British English novels suitable for learning English

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, british-english, literature

I am learning English and for that purpose (among other things) I want to read a few novels. I have made a list of novels selected by personal taste, but since I am still learning, I am afraid that some of them (written by overseas or 19th century authors) may be not suitable for me (since, at this stage, I want to focus in modern British English). Could you confirm/discard if they are written in a suitable English for learning? I hesitate about the following books:

1. J.M. Coetzee. Elizabeth Costello.
2. S. Rushdie. Midnight's Children.
3. R.K. Narayan (several novels).
4. E.M. Forster. Howards End.
5. F.M. Ford. Parade's End.
6. J. Galsworthy. The Forsyte Saga.
7. Henry James (several novels).

**EDIT.** Following the moderator's suggestion, please forget the list, and I will restate the question as follows. Could you suggest me a (minimum) "safe" date for a novel to be useful for my purpose?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! We can help with specific questions about English, but lists aren't a good fit for this format because there is no one answer that is "correct". See the [help] for more information about [what is on-topic here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Maybe instead of editing you should ask here https://literature.stackexchange.com I've not read those books, I can not advise about them but maybe you should start with short stories or books specifically adapted for learners before trying "the real thing".

Comment: I think RubioRic is right and you may get better answers from the [literature.se] community. Take a look at that site and let us know if you would like a moderator to migrate your question over there.

Comment: The language of the novels of Henry James can be difficult even for contemporary undergraduates. It's very good writing, but the sentences are quite long and contain many clauses, relying heavily upon subordination.

Comment: If your primary objective is to learn contemporary English, then I'd suggest you choose contemporary novels.

Comment: @ColleenV♦ Yes, please. Could any of you migrate my question to  literature.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @j.o. - It's best to check each Exchange's [help center](https://literature.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) before asking a question. The Literature.SE site says that the following questions are off-topic: _Questions about the English language in general; Questions asking for literature recommendations_. I don't think this question would fare much better there than here.

Answer (score 1):

These comments are just my personal opinion

1. J.M. Coetzee. Elizabeth Costello. - no idea
2. S. Rushdie. Midnight's Children. - modern british english
3. R.K. Narayan (several novels). - no idea
4. E.M. Forster. Howards End. - Edwardian (so 100 years old) but
   excellent british book
5. F.M. Ford. Parade's End. - think this is american
6. J. Galsworthy. The Forsyth Saga. - Modernish popular fiction
   (thriller)
7. Henry James (several novels). - also 100 years old, I believe these
   are quite difficult to understand stories in themselves as full of
   deep analogy. So maybe leave for now